# Can I eliminate redundent totals in google pivot tables?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, pivot-table

Given the general difficulty of doing much with google pivot table, I expect the answer to be "No".

In the snippet below I would like to keep lines with the totals in green shading and not see the lines with yellow shading.

[image]

Clicking the - signs collapses the detail leaving only the total.
It also would require a manual step to to go through and check each time the inventory changes.

In effect I want:

```
"if (number of details lines = 1) then (Don't show total)
```

Answer (score -1):

Click the [-] button on the row above the subtotal that you want to hide.

Comment: That does the reverse, -- keeps the total and hides the breakdown.

Comment: In addition, I was hoping for a way to do this programattically, as I don't want do do this line by line on a 500 line pivot table.

Comment: @SherwoodBotsford Thanks for the feedback and for updating your question. Regarding doing this programmatically please mention that an add [tag:google-apps-script] on the question.